# inner join and where in same query return blank error mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have run into some problem. This is the query that just return a blank page (I have tried error reporting on php and so on):

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT player.id, player.level, character.name, 
                              character.owner, character.owner 
                       FROM player 
                       INNER JOIN character ON player.id = character.owner
                       WHERE character.world  = '$world' ");

$res= mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error);
```

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL command in MySQL Workbench? Does it work there?

Comment: You should use mysqli for database stuff, that is faster better and stuff like that

Comment: Mark I will try MySQL Workbench,t hanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing parentheses after `mysql_error` and you should call it after calling `mysql_query`:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

If the query fails this should show the error message.

See the manual for more details on how to use [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) correctly.

Comment: It still just return a blank page and no error message but if I change something that I know the query will fail on it show it..

Comment: Little input, it show successful in workbench but I don't get any output. On the future "explain" it says "2 row(s) returned". but on "execute the statement" I don't get any. I tried one simple query and it did output the info from the query I executed.

Comment: @Kraziee: I think you should try to get the query working in WorkBench first. I'd guess that the reason you get no rows is because your query is wrong. I'd suggest double-checking that the WHERE condition and the JOIN condition are correct. You should read the output from EXPLAIN with a grain of salt. The row counts you get from EXPLAIN are only estimates based on table statistics. They are not actual values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT player.id, player.level, character.name, 
                          character.owner, character.owner 
                   FROM player 
                   INNER JOIN character ON player.id = character.owner
                   WHERE character.world  = '$world' ") or die(mysql_error());

$res= mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

This will display your error incase you missed something.